# Why is the maximum path length for convolutional layer $O(n/k)$ in attention is all you need paper?

Tags: conv-neural-network, convolution, attention

In the table-1 third row it is being mentioned. Why is it $O(n/k)$?  Take for example 1d convolution of 2 over 9 tokens with stride $1$. It won't be $n/k$ or $9/2=4.5$ rather it would be roughly $n-1$ or $8$.

The paper did not mention about stride, so I assumed it would work for any stride.

**From paper:** ([link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03762.pdf))

A single convolutional layer with kernel width k < n does not connect all pairs of input and output
positions. ***Doing so requires a stack of O(n/k) convolutional layers in the case of contiguous kernels,***
or O(logk(n)) in the case of dilated convolutions [18],

Comment: Can you provide the link to the paper? Seems that got lost when you first wrote this question.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03762.pdf Here is the link